# Trying to make a grid with different elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to build a grid where I can have multiple layers for instance instead of a 3x3:

```
 X X X
 X X X
 X X X
```

I can have another 3x3 layer continue right under that:

```
 X X X
 X X X
 X X X
 Y Y Y
 Y Y Y
 Y Y Y
 Z Z Z
 Z Z Z
 Z Z Z
```

and make as much layers as I want with different tile prefabs

to build a regular grid with custom width and height

```
int width, height;
Tile tilePrefab;

  Void BuildGrid(){
  for (int x = 0); x < width; x++;){
   for (int y = 0); x < height; y++);
    var tile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(x,y), Quaternion.identity)
 }
}
```

Comment: You know what's lacking here? 1: a problem statement, 2: a question

Comment: Check out 2D Arrays

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't instantiate "Tile" objects. If you want to instantiate every tile, you can use this code below. tile prefabs count will define layer count.

```
int width, height;
GameObject[] tilePrefabs;

Void BuildGrid(){
    for (int layer = 0; layer < tilePrefabs.Length; layer++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                var tile = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[layer], new Vector3(x,y), Quaternion.identity);
                tile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = layer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

better solution will be to use Tilemap api to create tiles correctly:

```
int width, height;
Tilemap[] tilemaps;
Tile[] tiles;

Void BuildGrid(){
    for (int layer = 0; layer < tiles.Length; layer++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                tilemaps[layer].SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y), tiles[layer]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here tilemaps should be created in advance in unity or you can create them in previous code too. "Tilemap renderer" component can help you to set layers' order.